# Python - character encoding and decoding problems

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, codec, urlopen

- I have got 1 source file with utf-8 characters (names)
- I have got 1    out file with same character encoding.
- I am working    with a html page,    paste and cut the useful
  information for me to    out file.
- I use "éáűúőóüöäđĐ' characters in my "friendsNames" txt file.

And I gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rendszergazda\workspace\achievements\hiba.py", line 9, in <module>
    s = str(urlopen("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/arathor/"+str(names[0])+"/achievement").read(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

What do you think? What is my problem?

```
from urllib import urlopen
import codecs

result = codecs.open("C:\Users\Desktop\Achievements\Result.txt", "a", "utf-8")
fh = codecs.open("C:\Users\Desktop\Achievements\FriendsNames.txt", "r", "utf-8")
line = fh.readline()
names = line.split(" ")
fh.close()

s = urlopen("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/arathor/"+str(names[0])+"/achievement").read(), encoding='utf8')
result.write(str(s))
result.close()
```

Comment: Just for information: The character `0xfeff` is a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Additionally your error message and your code sample do not match.

Comment: If you want to learn more about unicode, I strongly recommend http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that you're calling `str(array[0])`, where `array[0]` is a unicode string. This means it'll be encoded in the default encoding, which for some reason in your case seems to be `cp1250`. (Did you mess with `sys.setdefaultencoding()`? Don't do that.)

To get bytestrings out of unicode, you should explicitly *encode* the unicode. Don't just call `str()` on it. Encode it using the encoding the result should have (which in the case of URLs is somewhat difficult to guess at, but in this case is probably UTF-8.) So, use `array[0].encode('utf-8')'. You may also need to quote the non-ASCII characters in your URL, although that depends on what the remote end expects.

Comment: But I gave a new problem, in utf-8 xy.write "eat" my "\n" , I tried this: **u"\u000A"** (utf-8 new line), but it does not work :(

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the problem. u"\u00A" is the same thing as u"\n", and it's unicode, not UTF-8. (See http://bit.ly/unipain .) I suggest you post a new question describing your current problem.

Comment: You're probably on Windows and trying to open your output with Notepad, or something. Notepad only understands \r\n, but Word and Wordpad will display your file just fine.